# memcpy segfault

Tags: c

I am really struggling to see why the following code will not work and causes a segfault.

```
Car *newCar;
Car *oldCar;
newCar->engineSize = 1500;
memcpy(newCar, oldCar, sizeof(Car));
```

I am obviously missing something very fundamental here but don't know what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `newCar` is a wild (aka "dangling") pointer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for it.

```
Car* newCar = malloc(sizeof(Car));
Car* oldCar = malloc(sizeof(Car));
...
free(oldCar);
free(newCar);
```

If you don't need to use the pointer elsewhere, you could use stack-allocation.

```
Car newCar;
Car oldCar;
newCar.engineSize = 1500;
memcpy(&newCar, &oldCar, sizeof(newCar));
```

Answer (score 3):

A variable definition such as

```
Car* newCar;
```

only gives you a *pointer* variable. All it can do is hold the address of something called a `Car`. The memory size of a `Car` is unknown here, but it can easily be thousands of times larger than what the mere *pointer* requires.

You need to allocate memory for the actual value before changing it, either through field assignment to e.g. `engineSize` or by calling `memcpy()`:

```
newCar = malloc(sizeof *newCar);
memcpy(newCar, oldCar, sizeof *newCar);
```

Note that there's in general no need to use `memcpy()`, assuming this is a `struct` they are assignable:

```
*newCar = *oldCar;
```

This reads cleaner, and has less chance of programmer error.

Also, note that the `engineSize` must be set after the copying is done, otherwise it will be overwritten when you copy:

```
newCar = malloc(sizeof *newCar);
*newCar = *oldCar;
newCar->engineSize = 1500;
```

Answer (score 1):

`newCar` needs to be allocated some memory before you can write to it.

```
Car* newCar = malloc(sizeof(Car));
```

Right now what you have is just an pointer which points to some random address in the memory and you attempting to write to that address, which results in **Undefined Behavior** and a seg fault.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't allocated any memory, so your `newCar` and `oldCar` stack variables have random values and point to some arbitrary memory locations that may not be mapped by the process.

Answer (score 1):

As written, the code is using uninitialized pointers.  Both `newCar` and `oldCar` are pointers that could have any value, so the assignment and the memcpy result in an attempt to write to whatever address they happen to point to.  In reality, the compiler should warn about the use of an uninitialized variable; make sure you have warnings enabled.

Another way is to allocate on the stack:

```
Car newCar;
Car oldCar;
newCar.engineSize = 1500;
memcpy(&newCar, &oldCar, sizeof(Car));
```

Or malloc the memory:

```
Car *newCar = malloc( sizeof(Car));
Car *oldCar = malloc( sizeof(Car));
newCar->engineSize = 1500;
memcpy(newCar, oldCar, sizeof(Car));
```

Comment: You can't ignore the `(` ... `)` in `sizeof(Car)` because `Car` is a type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate space for your `Car` instances. Try

```
Car *newCar = (Car *)malloc(sizeof(Car);
Car *oldCar = (Car *)malloc(sizeof(Car);;
newCar->engineSize = 1500;
memcpy(newCar, oldCar, sizeof(Car));
```